# Neater representation of a list

Tags: r, list

Suppose I have function that returns a list

```
fun <- function()
{
    return(list(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6), c(7,8,9)))
}
```

Now writing `fun()` gives me

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 4 5 6

[[3]]
[1] 7 8 9
```

But is there a way to get something like this?

```
list(c(1,2,3), 
     c(4,5,6), 
     c(7,8,9))
```

**EDIT**: how can I preserve both a nice output and a possibility of making operations on the list that is returned?

Comment: Could you just put the output of the function through `dput`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're probably wanting a prettified version of `dput`:

```r
fun <- function(x) {
  text_con <- textConnection("output", "w")
  dput(x, text_con)
  close(text_con)
  formatR::tidy_source(text = output, args.newline = TRUE, width = 40)
}
```

So for example:

```
mylist <- list(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6), c(7,8,9))

fun(mylist)
#> list(
#>     c(1, 2, 3),
#>     c(4, 5, 6),
#>     c(7, 8, 9)
#> )
```

---

**EDIT**

If you want a list to be printed in a particular way, but otherwise maintain all of the functionality of a list, it's probably best to create an S3 class with its own printing method:

```r
special_list <- function(...) structure(list(...), class = "special_list")

as.special_list <- function(x) `class<-`(as.list(x), "special_list")

print.special_list <- function(x) {
  text_con <- textConnection("output", "w")
  dput(unclass(x), text_con)
  close(text_con)
  formatR::tidy_source(text = output, args.newline = TRUE, width = 40)
  invisible(x)
}
```

Now you can create a `special_list` like this:

```
my_list <- special_list(a = c(1, 2, 3), b = letters[1:3])

my_list
#> list(
#>     a = c(1, 2, 3),
#>     b = c("a", "b", "c")
#> )
```

and it retains the functionality of any other list

```r
my_list$a <- 2 * my_list$a

my_list
#> list(
#>     a = c(2, 4, 6),
#>     b = c("a", "b", "c")
#> )
```

It just means that you need to make a `special_list` instead of a normal `list` if you want to print a list this way. If you want to create a `special_list` from an existing list, you can do:

```r
newlist <- list(a = 1:3)

newlist
#> $a
#> [1] 1 2 3

newlist <- as.special_list(newlist)

newlist
#> list(a = 1:3)
```

Comment: thanks! but is there a way to print this output while still maintaining the ability to make operations on my list (that is the output)? using both `return()` and `cat()` with `sink()` doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @thesecond see my update for a fairly simple solution

Comment: Your `print.special_list` should invisibly return `x`. I would probably not bother creating a new S3 type, and instead override `print.list`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I was going to over-ride `print.list` but was surprised to find that it doesn't exist (presumably `print.default` gets used for lists, and we don't want to over-write that). Good point about the invisible return though.

Comment: @AllanCameron Well you can just add it, then it exists. ;-) Admittedly it’s a bit more complicated because that in itself won’t be called by `print`, for reasons I have never understood, but you can override `print.default` transparently to cause it being triggered. But yeah, that’s more convoluted. At some point I need to take the time to understand *properly* how S3 lookup works for builtin types.

Answer (score 1):

this function returns exactly that - but I may have misunderstood

```
print_list <- function(x){
  cat("list(", paste(x, collapse="\n     "), ")", sep="")
}

print_list(fun())
```

Adding that to your existing function:

```
fun <- function(){
  cat("list(", paste(list(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6), c(7,8,9)), collapse="\n     "), ")", sep="")
}
```

As noted in the comments, you could (if not bothered about the line breaks) use `dput(fun())`

Comment: thanks! but is there a way to print this output while still maintaining the ability to make operations on my list (that is the output)? using both `return()` and `cat()` with `sink()` doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: That isn’t really a generally usable function. It works in this specific case but not with most other data types.